# How can I extend textbackground horizontally in ConTeXt?

Tags: sectioning, context, backgrounds

I am using ConTeXt and I would like to give my section heads a background extending slightly into the left and right margins (0.5 cm or so). I want the text itself to be in the usual position. I originally tried to do this with a framed (with no luck),  and switched to trying a textbackground as suggested by a thread in the context mailing  list archives.

I am able to extend the background in all directions by using
backgroundoffset, but I only want it to be extended in the horizontal
directions.

MLE:

```
\setuppapersize[A4]
\setupindenting[never]
\setuplayout[grid=yes]

\definetextbackground[headback][background=color, backgroundcolor=black, frame=off, location=paragraph] % if I add backgroundoffset=0.5cm I can get it to extend in ALL directions
\setuphead[subject][deeptextcommand=\headback, color=white]

\starttext
\startsubject[title={With an overhanging bar of colour}]

Some stuff

\stopsubject
\stoptext
```

Cross posting disclaimer: I also sent this to the ConTeXt mailing list Wednesday morning, but I'm still waiting for an admin to approve the email and my list subscription.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution using `framed`. I simply set `command=...` key of `\setuphead`.I don't think that `deeptextcommand` is the right key as the makeup etc get applied *after* the `deeptextcommand`.

```
\showframe % for visualizing the page layout
\definemeasure[HeadFrameWidth][\dimexpr\textwidth+0.5cm\relax]
\defineframed
  [HeadFramed]
  [
    width=\measured{HeadFrameWidth},
    align=normal,
    background=color,
    backgroundcolor=black,
    foregroundcolor=white,
    % Play around with this setting if you wish
    toffset=0.5em,
    boffset=0.5em,
  ]
\define[2]\HeadCommand
    {\HeadFramed{#1#2}}

\setuphead[subject][command=\HeadCommand]

\starttext
\startsubject[title={With an overhanging bar of colour}]
Some stuff
\stopsubject
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

If you want the frame to extend in both directions, there are various ways to do that. One is to set the frame width to `\textWidth + 0.5cm * 2`, the `loffset` of the frame to be `0.5cm` and add a `\hskip -0.5cm` before inserting the frame. So, effectively it looks like that the frame is extending to the left. (In the example below I changed the colors so that you can see the page margins drawn using `\showframe`:

```
\showframe % for visualizing the page layout

\definemeasure[HeadFrameWidth][\dimexpr\textwidth+0.5cm*2\relax]

\definecolor[gray][s=0.2,t=0.1,a=1]

\defineframed
  [HeadFramed]
  [
    width=\measured{HeadFrameWidth},
    align=normal,
    background=color,
    backgroundcolor=gray,
    foregroundcolor=black,
    loffset=0.5cm,
    % Play around with this setting if you wish
    toffset=0.5em,
    boffset=0.5em,
  ]
\define[2]\HeadCommand
    {\hskip -0.5cm\HeadFramed{#1#2}}

\setuphead[subject][command=\HeadCommand]

\starttext
\startsubject[title={With an overhanging bar of colour}]
Some stuff
\stopsubject
\stoptext
```

[image]

However, this is beginning to get very hackish. At this stage, it might be simpler to just draw the background using metapost.

```
\showframe % for visualizing the page layout

\definecolor[gray][s=0.2,t=0.1,a=1]

\startuseMPgraphic{extended}
  fill OverlayBox leftenlarged 0.5cm rightenlarged 0.5cm withcolor OverlayColor;
  setbounds currentpicture to OverlayBox;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineoverlay[extended][\useMPgraphic{extended}]

\defineframed
  [HeadFramed]
  [
    frame=off,
    width=broad,
    align=normal,
    background=extended,
    backgroundcolor=gray,
    foregroundcolor=black,
  ]
\define[2]\HeadCommand
    {\HeadFramed{#1#2}}

\setuphead[subject][command=\HeadCommand]

\starttext
\startsubject[title={With an overhanging bar of colour}]
Some stuff
\stopsubject
\stoptext
```

Comment: »makeup etc get applied *after* the `deeptextcommand`«  What do you mean by that?  In `deeptextcommand` you get the unprocessed title as an argument, in `textcommand` you get it with additional strut, style, and color.  The dimensions of the page (which is what I understand by makeup) is already known at the point of `deeptextcommand`.

Comment: @HenriMenke: I meant formatting commands etc. I haven't checked this, but from what I remember, the order is `\command{\numbercommand{\numberformatting{\deepnumbercommand{<number>}}}\textcommand{\textformating{\deeptextcommand{<head>}}}}`. `deep...command` are meant for things like `\Uppercase`.

Comment: I actually had something similar to this before when I was trying using framed, but I need the coloured background to extend to the left as well as right.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with `background` but not with `textbackground`.  Anyway, I would use Aditya's solution.

```
\showframe

\setuppapersize[A4]
\setupindenting[never]
\setuplayout[grid=yes]

\definebackground
  [headback]
  [background=color,
   backgroundcolor=black,
   frame=off,
   roffset=.5cm]

\setuphead
  [subject]
  [deeptextcommand=\headback,
   color=white]

\starttext
\startsubject[title={With an overhanging bar of colour}]

Some stuff

\stopsubject
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: I need the coloured background to extend to the left as well as right. I have changed the question to make this clearer. I realised after viewing the answers that interpreting the original question the way I meant it depended on a single plural-s.